# Exit for-loop in case first error occurs

Tags: labview

The VI contains a for loop. In case of error i want to stop the for-loop.
So i unbundle the error line. and make a while-loop round the for-loop.
Setting is *stop on error* .
My issue: How to get out the value from the for-loop?
* Shifting register is not really working
* indexing cannto be configured (due to error line is a cluster?

Comment: I am not very familiar with conditional for loops, but it sounds weird. Have you tried replacing the for loop with while loop ?

Comment: The for-loop iterates x times. if there is an error within this five times it has to stop / break the for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

For-Loop --> right click on border --> add condition terminal --> connect this with the unbundle element

[image: Screenshot of solution (yellow)]

Comment: you can actually wire an error wire (yellow) directly into the conditional stop terminal and it will automatically assume you want it to stop on an error.  This removes the need to unbundle the error cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of LabVIEW version you are using you can do it differently. Conditional for loop was introduced sometimes at LabVIEW 8.6, before that version the only solution is to use while loop instead of for loop.
No need to unbundle the error cluster, it can be wired directly into stop terminal.
Error wire is also can be wired directly into boolean nodes in the latest versions of LabVIEW.

Comment: Correct, in addition to direct wiring i use the code and text now also for information purpose.